# Is there a way to sort an elasticsearch _score by ASC?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an indexed ES of 574,279,238 documents. Since this, I have to manage lot of results when I query the DB.

Is there a way to get results based on a ASC-sorted _score ? I would like to see the X "baddest" results ES gives me... even if I have more than 1 million results...

'sort' => [ {'_score' : {'order':'asc'} } ]

that's not working...

Thanks for your help

Comment: `"sort": [
    {"_score": "asc"} ]` doesn't work?

Comment: no…

`'sort' => [ {'_score' : {'order’:’desc’} } ]  `

that’s working…

`'sort' => [ {'_score' : {'order’:’asc’} } ]  `

and

`'sort' => [ {'_score' : ‘asc’ } ]  `


does not…

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If `desc` works, `asc` should as well. What do you mean by doesn't work? What do you expect to see and what actually do you get back?

Comment: You're right... My mistake... My script was returning an empty response because of the "max_score" is NULL... no way to get this sort order + the max_score ?

Comment: You can't do anything with max_score. And if it's null then your documents were not scored.

Comment: When I sort my query by DESC; I have a max_score filled with the best relevance... All my results have score. When I sort my query by ASC; all my results have a score; but the max_score is null... I don't want to use it in my query; I just want to get it like if i'm sorting by DESC...

Comment: Please, provide the query and the result of sorting by ASC and by DESC. Also, what ES version is this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is available. You may ingest some documents and check it. Please follow my instruction on [sort result by term frequency count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939959/sort-result-by-term-frequency-count).

Run following query and find out the expected result:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/movies/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "godfather"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```