# sort result by term frequency count

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

If there are 2 documents which have word "world" in them 5 times & 2 times respectively.

So I want the document which has word "world" 5 times to be listed first followed by document which has word "world" 2 times.

How do i sort this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any need to sort it. If you have documents as you mentioned, and you are searching a particular word which is appearing more then one, two or three in your case, elastic search will calculate its score automatically and would return the document by score sorting.

To try this ingest some documents:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/1" -d'
{
  "title": "The Godfather",
  "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
  "year": 1972,
  "genres": [
    "Crime",
    "Drama"
  ]
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/2" -d'
{
  "title": "The Godfather Godfather",
  "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
  "year": 1972,
  "genres": [
    "Crime",
    "Drama"
  ]
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/movie/3" -d'
{
  "title": "The Godfather Godfather Godfather",
  "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
  "year": 1972,
  "genres": [
    "Crime",
    "Drama"
  ]
}'
```

After ingestion run this query and see the result:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/movies/_search" -d'
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "godfather"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This will return the document three on top because it has "godfather" multiple time