# Elasticsearch: Give higher score to long title

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch database in which all documents have a **title** field and are queried by this field.

By default, Elasticsearch search gives higher score to document with short **title**. But, in my use case, short titles are irrelevant.

For example, when I search for 'Deep Learning' the first results are

- 'Deep Learning'
- 'Machine Learning and Deep Learning'
- 'Semi-Supervised Deep Learning With Memory'

I would like the document titled 'Semi-Supervised Deep Learning With Memory' to appear before the document titled 'Deep Learning'.

Is there any solution to achieve that without changing the mapping?

Thanks

Comment: may be you can try to reverse sort order , like explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36941268/6490744

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to compute the content length ant the ingesting time, keep it in a field and use it with a function score query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": { "title": "elasticsearch" }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['title_length'].value * _score"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can use a script score query which use the field size if you have a keyword mapping on this field.
If not you will have to enable field data on it. But it's very expensive and not recommended.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": { "title": "elasticsearch" }
      },
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['title'].value.length() * _score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```